# How do I look after my House-Plant?

Tags: fallen-london

I have been Attending to the Needs of a Singular Plant for some time now.

I try to do my best, but it seems that all the Opportunities that I have to care for my little plant are solely luck based. I find myself constantly taking one step forward and two steps back.

**How can I consistently improve the state of my Singular Plant?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different Opportunity cards regarding your Singular Plant: one of them is *The Noted Orchid-Grower Consults*, which gives you a chance to improve your plant (and a chance the grower is entirely wrong, and gives you incorrect advice). As you've noticed, it's random. But there are two other Opportunity cards that can help: *Your House-plant*, which allows you to improve your shrubbery by spending Moon-Pearls, and *Your Green Companion*, which allows you to grow your green thing by spending Jade. (You can also sing or talk to your plant on those two cards, which has a small chance of improving things and no chance of damaging the plant, but it's chancy.)

If the Random Number God hates you, just discard all of the *Noted Orchid-Grower* cards, and spend money on the other two. If you're cheap, then discard the *Noted Orchid-Grower* cards and sing or talk to your plant with the other two; it will be slower, but much cheaper.